# Cloning the task list view datatable in custom LWC (Status value and clickable button in same column)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, style

I'm trying to create a Lightning datatable in Salesforce that displays a status value and a clickable button icon in the same column similar to the task recent view table.
[image]
The button should be different depending on the value of the status field (i.e. "Open" or "Complete"). I've tried using the type: 'button-icon' column type with typeAttributes to dynamically set the button icon and label based on the status value, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality with a single column in the Lightning datatable? Or do I need to create separate columns for the status value and the button icon? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an htm table and an apex helper class...try the code below

**Apex:**

```
public with sharing class GetTaskController {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<TaskWrapper> getTasks(){
    try {
        
        List<Task> tasks = [
            SELECT Id, Subject, Priority, Status
            FROM Task
            WHERE Status IN ('Completed', 'Not Started')
            LIMIT 20
        ];

        List<TaskWrapper> task_wrapper_list = new List<TaskWrapper>();

        for(Task t : tasks){
            TaskWrapper tw = new TaskWrapper();
            tw.TaskId = t.Id;
            tw.Subject = t.Subject;
            tw.Priority = t.Priority;
            tw.Status = t.Status;
            switch on t.Status {
                when  'Completed'{
                    tw.ButtomIcon = 'standard:task';
                }
                when 'Not Started' {
                    tw.ButtomIcon = 'standard:drafts';
                }
            }
            task_wrapper_list.add(tw);
        }

        return task_wrapper_list;
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public class TaskWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public string TaskId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Subject;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Priority;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Status;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string ButtomIcon;
}
```

}

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import wrapperData from "@salesforce/apex/GetTaskController.getTasks";


export default class StackExchangeTableExemple extends LightningElement {

  tasks;

  @wire(wrapperData)
  wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
      if (data) {
          this.tasks = data;
      }
      else if(error){
          if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
              let errors = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
              console.log('ERRO: ' + errors);
          }
          else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
              let errors = error.body.message;
              console.log('ERRO: ' + errors);
          }
      }
  }

  handleClick(event){
      // do something
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" aria-labelledby="element-with-table-label other-element-with-table-label">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Subject">Subject</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Priority">Priority</div>
        </th>
        <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
      <template for:each={tasks} for:item="tw">
        <tr  key={tw.TaskId} class="slds-hint-parent">
          <td>{tw.Subject}</td>
          <td>{tw.Priority}</td>
          <td>
            <lightning-icon icon-name={tw.ButtomIcon} size="small"></lightning-icon>
            <lightning-button variant="base" label={tw.Status} onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </template>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, can we do it in standard lightning-datatable, I want all the functionality like sorting, etc which the standard table has.

Comment: I find it more difficult to implement this customization in the default datatable, but it is possible! I think the lightning-datatable is stuck, but you can do everything that the default datatable does in slds-table, including sorting... I'll leave some links that can help you...

Comment: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#Sorted-Ascending

Comment: https://alistechtips.com/2019/10/02/lwc-table-sort/